# How to create incrimental id's for object instances

Tags: python, object, identifier

I am working on a very simple game project, and was wondering how to create a working incremental id for my instances of the Bullet class that would function basically as:

```
class Bullet:

     def __init___():
         pass

bulletnumber = 5

i = 0

while (i < bulletnumber):

     str('bullet' + 0) = Bullet()
     i += 1
```

Now I recognize this doesn't work because you can't assign a string to the id for an object in Python, but this is essentially what I want do. Create an incremental way to create instances of objects. But this doesn't work. I don't know if I should use an array or something else.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by `id`? Do you mean the result of the built-in `id()` function as applied to your objects? Or do you mean the name of the variables in your program? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a list:

```
bullets = [Bullet() for _ in range(bulletnumber)]
```

Then you can use individual bullets like so:

```
print bullets[4].speed
```